# Calling R Script from PHP Page

Tags: php, html, r, calling-convention

I have a Rscript which I want to call from my PHP page. It saves two plots in a particular location and those are need to be displayed on the browser. The script is running fine in R Studio and plots are being saved at their respective locations. However, no output is being shown on browser.

```
<?php



exec("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\Rscript code.R");




?>

<html>
<body>
<img src="C:/EasyPHP-12.1/www/RLinl/myplot1.jpeg">
<br>
<img src="C:\EasyPHP-12.1\www\RLinl\myplot2.jpeg">
<br> 
<img src="C:/EasyPHP-12.1/www/RLinl/myplot3.jpeg">
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any problem in this call to the script ? The script uses a dataset and no parameters are required to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="/RLinl/myplot1.jpeg">
<br>
<img src="/RLinl/myplot2.jpeg">
<br> 
<img src="/RLinl/myplot3.jpeg">
<br>
```

the above code is assuming that your document root is www and the images are being generated from R

Comment: yes the images are being stored here by the Rscript.
When checking error logs, it says:
'Rscript' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: That means exec() can't find Rscript in that path. Are you use this is correct? C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\Rscript?

Comment: No, it means that the image link should be changes like above, because the script is in php, apache is serving content. Apache does not take absolute url. It takes relative url with root as `www` or other custom location if any set by administrator

Comment: @DannyH The path is all correct. Do we need to add anything to the PATH variable ?

Comment: @georoot Thanks for rectifying the bug.